# GUID of a custom SSRS report Published in Dynamics CRM 365

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm

I have a custom SSRS report published to MS Dynamics 365 that I am trying to call on a form button-click. I want to run the report for a selected record of an Entity. I am able to retrieve the EntityGuid run-time and pass it to the report.

- How do I get the ReportGuid in order to pass it as an argument in the url ?
- What is an entityType in the Url and where do I find the value of a custom entity?

Url looks like this -

```
var url = serverUrl + "/" + organizationName + "/crmreports/viewer/viewer.aspx?action=run&context=records&helpID=" + rdlName  + "&id={"+reportGuid+"}&records=" + entityGuid + "&recordstype=" + entityType;
window.open(url);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [XrmToolbox](http://www.xrmtoolbox.com/) can help with both questions:

Using the FetchXML tester, this query will retrieve the names and GUID's of all the reports:

```
<fetch>
    <entity name="report" >
        <attribute name="name" />
        <attribute name="reportid" />
    </entity>
</fetch>
```

And the MetaData Browser shows each entity's ObjectTypeCode (a.k.a. EntityTypeCode or "etc").

[image]

And for the record, CRM provides a way to run a report from a form. After you configure the report to be available from the form, go to ellipsis and select Run Report:

[image]

Comment: Can we get the entityGuid runtime rather than hardcoding it keeping in mind the GUID might change when we move code between environments?

Is there any other way to see the ObjectTypeCode other than using XrmToolBox metadata browser?

Comment: In your question you said, "I am able to retrieve the EntityGuid run-time and pass it to the report." Are you looking to get the Report Id at run time?

Comment: My bad, I meant to ask for the ReportGuid.

Comment: You can use the web api to retrieve the report's ID by name, as well as the entity metadata, which should contain the ObjectTypeCode. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt607833.aspx. And please note that I updated the answer to include the native way to run a report from a form.

Answer (score 2):

Open Dynamics CRM -> Navigate to reports -> Find report you wand to get guid of -> select it and click "Edit" button in the Command Bar -> check url of window that popped up -> it should be something like https://yourorgname.crm.dynamics.com/CRMReports/reportproperty.aspx?id=%7b8484A9E3-3F8B-E611-80EE-C4346BAC897C%7d
Part after id= is your guid. In my case it is "8484A9E3-3F8B-E611-80EE-C4346BAC897C"
Good luck.